# How can I use dask.dataframe to_csv when i have bigdata

Tags: python, dask

I just want to  save CSV file using dask.I got dat fiel which is over 30GB.
there are no problem with read_csv. 
but after work i need to save it as CSV file. 
It doesn't work. Help me

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("E:/bigdata/H_2015_04.dat", sep="|", header=None)
df.to_csv("E:/bigdata/1.csv")
```

There are error messages like..

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 894, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 993, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1122, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1167, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1215, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1905, in pandas._libs.parsers._try_int64
MemoryError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Memory error due to file size.You can read part of the data at a time using the following method**

```
reader = pd.read_csv(file_path, iterator=True)
#Read lines 0 to 1000
chunk = reader.get_chunk(1000)
#Read lines 1000 to 2000
chunk = reader.get_chunk(1000)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is really helpful. I find what I was wrong. Thank you.